# Composable as method parameter

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a Scaffold composable which is used as the basis of all screens :

```
    @Composable
fun ScreenScaffold(
    navController: NavController? = null,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    topBar: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    hasBottomNavBar : Boolean = false,
    hasGradient : Boolean = true,
    stickyContainerContent: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    showStickyContainer: Boolean = false,
    surfaceMode: SurfaceMode = SurfaceMode.OnBackground,
    stickyContainerSurfaceMode: SurfaceMode = surfaceMode,
    onBackButtonPressed: (() -> Boolean)? = null ,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
```

And TopBar parameter is a composable like this:

```
@Composable
fun TopBar(
    title: String? = null,
    titleAlign: TextAlign = TextAlign.Start,
    hasLargeTitle: Boolean = false,
    largeTitleTextStyle: TopBarLargeTitleTextStyle = TopBarLargeTitleTextStyle.LARGE,
    hasBackButton: Boolean = false,
    backButtonTint: Long = OneAppTheme.colors.topNavIconColor,
    backButtonOnClick: () -> Unit = {},
    rightButtonImageToken: String? = null,
    rightButtonTint: Long = OneAppTheme.colors.topNavIconColor,
    rightButtonOnClick: () -> Unit = {},
    surfaceMode: SurfaceMode = SurfaceMode.OnBackground,
    scrollBehavior: TopBarScrollBehavior? = null,
) {
```

Right now if I wanna pass a callback for back button handling, I have to pass it twice for both ScreenScaffold and TopBar (onBackButtonPressed and backButtonOnClick respectively). How can I pass that callback just once to ScreenScaffold and then somehow pass it to TopBar?

Thanks.

Comment: Why is it problem to pass twice?

Comment: Because you have to remember that, and in our codebase I can see that a lot of people have forgotten this!

Comment: The easiest thing I can think of is to use [Locally scoped data with CompositionLocal](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal).

Comment: The only solution I can think of you can create customScaffoldWithTopBar component and you can use backPressed parameter both.

Answer (score 3):

You can define the topbar/scaffold in one wrapper function like below and provide the scope ie, BoxScope and use it.

```
@Composable
fun WrapperFun(content: @Composable BoxScope.() -> Unit) {
Box {
    //add topbar/scaffold
    content(this) }
}
```

Usage:

```
@Composable
fun Test() {
WrapperFun {
    Text(text = "Test", modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
}}
```